# Esconder dados da URL e mudar a exibição

Tags: php, javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, onde passo um valor em uma variável e carrego ela na minha url, através no formulário utilizando o método POST, assim, possuo a Url:

```
$url = "../usuario/detalhamento.php?foo=$id";
echo "<td><center><a href='$url' class='btn btn-primary btn-block
value='$id'>$id</a></center></td>";`
```

Aí, funciona lindo, só que minha url na página que chamei aparece assim:

> http://127.0.0.1:8082/meusite/usuario/detalhamento.php?foo=1

O problema de deixar assim é que, qualquer um pode chegar e digitar um ID no final e acessar outras informações. 
O que eu queria é saber como esconder tudo o que tem depois da "?" ou substituir tudo por "#" por exemplo, só não queria que ficasse a mostra.

Comment: URL amigáveis. Estou sem tempo de te dar um exemplo, mas tenho certeza que alguém vai postar uma resposta abaixo.

Comment: Escondendo isso você sabe que vai ter problemas de SEO, isso não é uma preocupação para você? Se não for, passa por GET ao invéz de POST.

Comment: Se o problema é só `privacidade` de informação, então você poderia gerar um `hash MD5` e passa ali  como parâmetro em vez de passar somente o `id` nu e cru.

Comment: Como disseram, se esconder terá problemas de SEO, ou seja, não será indexado pelos motores de busca, além de não resolver o problema uma vez que o recurso estará disponível na mesma. É preciso analisar quem pode ver os dados e em quais condições e com isso em mente implementar essas validações no servidor.

Comment: Sua aplicação deve prever IDs errados, pois escondendo-os ou não (seja lá como for), toda requisição HTTP pode ser forjada na íntegra, independente de ser GET, POST ou qq outra coisa. Sua preocupação é válida, mas o caminho escolhido pra resolver é ilusório. Se precisar mesmo de segurança, troque o ID por alguma chave que só valha pra sessão corrente, e/ou na aplicação principal verifique se o usuário logado tem direito de acessar o ID fornecido.

Answer (score 4):

> O problema de deixar assim é que, qualquer um pode chegar e digitar um ID no final e acessar outras informações.

Vamos começar por aqui.

Primeiramente isto é um fator de segurança, não de visibilidade. Ou seja, supor que o usuário **X** tenha acesso ao registros de **ID's**: **3, 2** e **5**. Já o usuário **Y** tenha acesso aos **ID's**: **8** e **1**.

Se o usuário **X** digitar na URL o **ID** **8** é papel da sua camada de segurança verificar se ele tem permissões de ver as informações daquele **ID**.

Vamos simular:

Em uma balada, onde existe área VIP e PISTA como são identificado as pessoas que tenham acesso a área VIP? No caso por pulseira. Se não houvesse essa "segurança" todos da pista poderiam entrar na VIP, correto?

Esta ideologia deverá ser imposta no seu sistema. Se o usuário digitar um ID aleatório na URL sua aplicação deverá processar o acesso dele naquele registro, não tentar esconder dele o ID.

> O que eu queria é saber como esconder tudo o que tem depois da "?"

Não há necessidade disso. Visibilidade não traz problemas se você tiver uma camada de segurança por trás. Você esta invertendo as bolas.

## Considerações

O importante não é a visibilidade do ID na URL, e sim o **ACL** de sua aplicação.

### SEO

Procure alguns artigos também sobre **SEO**, que para isso não é recomendado trabalhar com numeros na URL e sim SLUGS.

Answer (score 1):

Eu desenvolvi um sistema para uma empresa que iria trabalhar com cálculos financeiros, para evitar que o usuário tentasse alterar um registro sem autorização eu criei uma lógica mais ou menos assim:

```
$securityHash = sha1($idUsuario . $nivelAcesso . $url);
```

Sempre que ele acessava um link, o link ia da seguinte forma:

```
detalhes.php/1/f6ds8dsSAFsa768sa6f786sfa
```

Seria a mesma coisa que isso:

```
detalhes.php?id=1&sh=f6ds8dsSAFsa768sa6f786sfa
```

Na hora de renderizar a resposta, eu gerava o hash no servidor, e comparava com o da URL. Portanto, eu sabia que os usuários que estivessem ali, só poderia receber o hash X devido ao fato de ser acessível apenas como administrador, ou outro grupo qualquer.

E caso o hash fosse recusado, criei uma lógica para imediatamente bloquear o acesso do usuário e deslogar ele do sistema.